# CFEngine v2 not "propagating" Classes to client

Tags: linux, centos, cfengine

Morning,

I have a very odd issue with CFEngine 2.1.22.

I have two groups in cf.groups as below

```
 # devservers that need default sudoers
    group_default_sudoers = ( dev4_company_local 
                          dev5_company_local
                          dev6_company_local
                          dev7_company_local
                          dev8_company_local )



 # devservers that need db modified sudoers
    group_dbmod_sudoers = ( dev16_company_local )
```

And this is the nessessary lines from cf.main

```
actionsequence          = ( copy packages editfiles processes shellcommands tidy )

copy::
     group_default_sudoers::
    ${include_dir}/default_sudoers
            dest=/etc/sudoers
            owner=root
            group=root
            mode=440
            type=checksum
            backup=false

    group_dbmod_sudoers::
    ${include_dir}/dbmod_sudoers
            dest=/etc/sudoers
            owner=root
            group=root
            mode=440
            type=checksum
            backup=false
```

Now, the problem is, dev4,5,6 and 7 gets the new file instantly when I run cfagent on the clients, but dev8 and dev16 does not.

And I've been able to narrow down the problem to the "Defined Classes" with this command

```
cfagent -pv|grep Classes
```

And on all servers but dev8 and dev16 does the groups/classes show up (group_default_sudoers and group_dbmod_sudoers).

Anyone have any thoughts about this? I can't figure out how to get the classes defined and the configuration is identical.

Any hints or tips would be greatly appriciated, thanks.

Regards

Comment: Did you try to run cfagent with the `-d4` (expression eval debug) switch to see if it gives you any hint about the problem?

Comment: The output is of course very hard to parse, but I tried grep'ing for "sudo" and no match at all. The clients should get the updated groups and main files while running cfagent, and from what I can see they ain't updated so I suspect that might be main problem since that's what happens first of all.

Comment: I just copied cf.main and cf.groups manually to dev16 and ran cfagent -v and now it works, very peculiar, I'll try to find out why it doesn't get copied and add a proper Answer.

Comment: I found the answer, but can't make it an answer just yet 'couse of my reputation, but I'll add it within a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After realising the error was in that cf.main and cf.groups didn't get copied, I quickly understood something was wrong with the transfer of files and after comparing update.conf I found the error instantly, I changed update.conf on dev8 and dev16 and everything worked instantly.

This is what I think was the error, this did not exist on the faulty clients.

```
copy:
    $(master_cfinput)/ dest=$(local_cfinput)
    r=inf mode=600
    trustkey=true
    type=checksum
    ignore=cfservd.conf
    ignore=cfrun.hosts
    server=$(policyhost)
```

And in that folder was the two files, voilá!

Comment: +1 for using cfenigne2 (as I´m still doing )